# Price of original Apple ][ in 1980?

Tags: history, apple-ii, cost

Apple introduced the "new and improved" Apple ][ Plus in 1979, but continued to sell the original ][ until early 1981. I speculate that some customers must have chosen the original Apple ][ over the Plus for cost reasons.

What were the retail prices (listed or suggested) for the original Apple ][ before it was discontinued? Was it, in fact, less expensive than a Plus?

*Photo below of original Apple ][ motherboard* manufactured about March, 1980 ("8009" means week #9 of 1980). This *about 9 months after* the ][ Plus release.

[image]

Comment: And, while we're at it, what were the hardware differences between the II and II+ that might affect the cost? Obviously it added a couple more ROM chips, but I can't think of anything else off-hand. The remaining new circuitry, such as for chroma-suppression in text mode, seems as if it would be dirt cheap.

Comment: Are you sure that there were Apple II (no plus) sales after the II+ got introduced - beyond maybe a few in stock?. After all, the 'upgrade' can be done by exchanging a few parts, the manuals and a sticker on the box.

Comment: @Raffzahn The historical record I've seen indicate the original ][ and the ][ Plus were both for sale throughout 1980. Perhaps as much as 18 months from ][ Plus launch until the end of original ][ sales. I've seen this from multiple sources, but can't really vouch for it from any personal experience of buying an Apple at the time.

Comment: @cjs It could have been a matter of Apple simply charging more for a Plus because they could, or to cover Microsoft's royalty on BASIC, or perhaps base RAM configurations differed, with the ][ Plus maybe always having 48k. But I'm not even sure the ][ Plus was priced higher -just my speculation.

Comment: @Raffzahn I can personally vouch for original Apple ][ motherboards having date codes from after the ][ Plus launch. Maybe I should add a photo?

Comment: Browsing a January 1980 issue of Byte (thanks archive.org), I found 3 ads that sold the II or II+ for the same price ($975-$995). I also checked December 1980 and ... same thing ($925-$975). (Prices for 16K systems)

Comment: @KelvinSherlock I wonder if $995 was the suggested retail price for both ][ and ][ Plus with 16K RAM? Surprising, but possible.

Comment: list price was mentioned a couple times at around $1195 I think.

Comment: @KelvinSherlock For some reason, $1295 rings a bell in my mind.

Comment: apple2history.org gives original list prices of $1295 for the II (4K version?) and $1195 for the II+ (16K version?). It mentions 48K was "standard" for the II+ but 16K and 32K options were also available

Comment: @KelvinSherlock All useful info. Makes me wonder if the price of the original ][ also dropped to $1195 when the Plus was introduced. Weird if people still bought them at a _higher_ price than the Plus.

Comment: Byte, March 1979, before the II+ was introduced, I see a 16K II for $1195 and a 48K II for  $1795. June 1979, 16K II is $1195, 32K is $1345, 48K is $1495. There's also a discounted ($1024) 16K II that puts apple list price at $1195. So it looks like Apple did the most un-Apple thing ever and increased the RAM and decreased the price over time.

Comment: I purchased an Apple ][ with 48kB, 2 floppy drives and the language card system (UCSD Pascal and extension to 64kB) for $2,600 in May 1980. I still have it.

Comment: I got my Apple II+ with 16 KiB around Christmas 1979 at  3000 Mark. Barebone.

Comment: @KevinWhite Would be a good  answer, especially if you can recall the cost breakdown, and why you didn't go for a Plus.

Comment: @BrianH - I don't remember but with the language card it could run either the integer or the FP BASIC. The language card replaced the ROMs in the address space.

Comment: In france it was around 10000 francs (aka 1500 euro)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the many helpful comments given, and reviewing dealer pricing of the Apple II and II Plus in old issues of Byte magazine from 1979/80, I've come up with what I think is a reasonable explanation and timeline.

The *most important factor affecting the price* of both Apple II models during the transition period of late 1979 and 1980 was the rapid decline in the price of the 16Kbit DRAM's used in both machines. The time period coincides with the entry of the highly competitive Japanese DRAM manufacturers that would go on to dominate the DRAM market in the 1980's. The falling price of DRAM prompted Apple to both lower the price of their machines and gradually increase the amount of RAM included.

The original retail price of the Apple II was US$1,298 (with 4 KiB RAM) and US$2,638 (with the maximum 48 KiB RAM).

By the time the Apple II Plus was released, Apple would offer both the Plus and the original for $1,195 with 16KiB of RAM. But the price of DRAM's fell so rapidly that by 1980, an Apple II or II Plus with 48KiB of RAM was selling for this same price of $1,195.

And this leads to my conclusion that, indeed, Apple continued to sell the original and the Plus for well over a year at the same price with the same RAM configuration. Dealers throughout 1980 seemed to frequently offer both machines, usually at the same price, and usually with $100 premium for each additional 16KiB of RAM. So, $995 for 16KiB, about $1,095 for 32KiB, and the canonical $1,195 for a fully-populated 48KiB AII or II Plus.

I suspect there are 2 reasons that the systems sold as equivalents for this time period.

1. For Apple's part, this is long before the industry had developed to a mature, just-in-time, model for supply chain and manufacturing management. Apple likely had plenty of work-in-progress Apple II's at the time the II Plus was ready, and their dealers likely also had significant inventory. Just clearing the channel would take some time, even if Apple immediately stopped ordering any material specific to the original AII. And they apparently did not halt Apple II sales immediately because of #2.
2. It's also likely that Apple's dealers and customers were onboard with a slow transition to the II Plus. The dealers had their inventory, and the issue for users was that AppleSoft Basic had a slow start. It was plagued by bugs, and its incompatibility with Integer Basic created some difficulty to overcome with the entrenched user base. Customers that wanted to avoid the early growing pains of AppleSoft could save BOTH the expense of a Language Card AND the hassle of loading Integer Basic by just purchasing an original AII.

By the time the stock of original Apples ran out in 1981, AppleSoft was more proven, and ready to become the new "standard" Basic. The bugs that had briefly hurt its reputation in the early releases were ironed out in the ROM version that shipped in the II Plus. And Applesoft's replacement of the legacy Basic was cemented when they went on to more than double computer sales that same year.

Those who opted for an original AII during the transition probably ended up just adding a Language Card later. Or, they simply held out for the more substantial improvements that would come with the Apple //e.

Comment: At least superficially, this answer seems to suggests that AppleSoft BASIC was still maturing and bugs were being ironed out. But wasn't the AppleSoft code more or less fixed from the moment the disk/tape based "AppleSoft II" came out in, what, 1978? As far as I know there was only ever one set of AppleSoft ROMs for the II/II+ era, and the RAM AppleSoft on the DOS 3.3 distribution disks was identical to that as well.

Comment: @TeaRex I agree the ROM AppleSoft had corrected the bugs in the earlier releases. I think the issue was more about users' perceptions of AppleSoft, especially if they were already invested in Integer Basic, and the incompatibility. I'll fix the answer to be more clear on that point.